# How to extract element from two similar tags in one code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I am trying to extract year from multiple xml files. Initially, the xml files are as follows,

```
<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile" returnVersion="2018v3.2">
  <ReturnHeader binaryAttachmentCnt="0">
    <!-- ... -->
    <TaxPeriodEndDt>2019-09-30</TaxPeriodEndDt>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ReturnHeader>
  <ReturnData documentCnt="12">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

I used

```
year = root.find('.//irs:TaxPeriodEndDt',ns).text[:4]
```

It had worked well. But in some xml files the tag is changed to TaxPeriodEndDate

```
<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile" returnVersion="2018v3.2">
  <ReturnHeader binaryAttachmentCnt="0">
    <!-- ... -->
    <TaxPeriodEndDate>2012-09-30</TaxPeriodEndDate>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ReturnHeader>
  <ReturnData documentCnt="12">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ReturnData>
</Return>
```

I tried to revise the code to

```
year = root.find('.//irs:TaxPeriodEndDt|.//irs:TaxPeriodEndDate',ns).text[:4]
```

It did not work. No error message, but no output. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Tag name mismatch in second example: `<TaxPeriodEndDate>2012-09-30</TaxPeriodEndDt>`

Comment: Also, try removing the dots from the xpath. They are not needed since your relative context is the root node.

Comment: Thank you, LMC. Sorry for the mismatching. I fixed it. But the dots are needed in the xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for [xpath in ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) is very limited. The union operator (`|`) doesn't appear to work and other options, like using the `self::` axis or `name()`/`local-name()` in a predicate, aren't supported.

I think your best bet is to use a try/except...

```py
try:
    year = root.find(".//irs:TaxPeriodEndDt", ns).text[:4]
except AttributeError:
    year = root.find(".//irs:TaxPeriodEndDate", ns).text[:4]
```

If you can switch to [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html), your original attempt with the union operator will work with a few small changes (mainly use `xpath()` instead of `find()` and use the `namespaces` keyword arg)...

```py
year = root.xpath(".//irs:TaxPeriodEndDt|.//irs:TaxPeriodEndDate", namespaces=ns)[0].text[:4]
```

Comment: The first code works. Thank you very much, Daniel.

Comment: @Daniel Haley Could you plesase check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646776/generate-dictionary-using-xml-data-python